# Python: how to open a file and loop through word for word and compare to a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file that is all strings and I want to loop through the file and check its contents against another file. Both files are too big to place in the code so I have to open each file with open method and then turn each into a loop that iterates over the file word for word (in each file) and compare every word for every word in other file. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I know how to open the files etc I just need the logic explained. How do I loop through each file at the same time and compare each word to each in another file? This may be an advanced topic. Not sure :(

Comment: What are you checking for? What sort of comparison are you making?

Comment: Literal. If one word is an exact match to another. It would be helpful if it was case insensitive but not necessary at this point. :)

Comment: I mean, what is it you're asking about these files? For example, do you need to know what words appear in both files, or what words appear in one file but not the other, or how many times the words from file A appear in file B, or what is it you want to know?

Comment: Got you. I want to know which words appear in both files. Eventually I want to write the words that appear in both a and b to c but right now I'm looking for a count of what is in both a and b.

Comment: Before you go too far, you should know that there is a standard Unix/Linux utility called "comm" (and a variation called "calm") that does this job.

Comment: @AustinHastings great thank you I will look into that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are both sorted, or if you can produce sorted versions of the files, then this is relatively easy. Your simplest approach (conceptually speaking) would be to take one word from file A, call it a, and then read a word from file B, calling it b. Either b is alphabetically prior to a, or it is after a, or they are the same. If they are the same, add the word to a list you're maintaining. If b is prior to a, read b from file B until b >= a. If equal, collect that word. If a < b, obviously, read a from A until a >= b, and collect if equal. 
Since file size is a problem, you might need to write your collected words out to a results file to avoid running out of memory. I'll let you worry about that detail.

If they are not sorted and you can't sort them, then it's a harder problem. The naive approach would be to take a word from A, and then scan through B looking for that word. Since you say the files are large, this is not an attractive option. You could probably do better than this by reading in chunks from A and B and working with set intersections, but this is a little more complex.

Putting it as simply as I can, I would read in a reasonably-sized chunks of file A, and convert it to a set of words, call that a1. I would then read similarly-sized chunks of B as sets b1, b2, ... bn. The union of the intersections of (a1, b1), (a1, b2), ..., (a1, bn) is the set of words appearing in a1 and B. Then repeat for chunk a2, a3, ... an.

I hope this makes sense. If you haven't played with sets, it might not, but then I guess there's a cool thing for you to learn about.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you and no they are single words each on their own line but completely random  I would think I could sort each into a new file and then pick back up at the beginning with comparing. I have not worked with sorts yet but it makes sense logically. I will just go back and learn the syntax. It'l be good for me anyways :) Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewMayes Glad I could help. Yeah, there's still a lot of stuff left for you to learn in this problem. Have fun!

Comment: any ideas what my syntax should look like. I have my lists sorted but the >= <= is throwing me off. I want to find all matches in both lists. So if "Johnny" is in one list I want to know how many times "Johnny" appears in the other list.. Not sure if that was clear before. 

Comment: This is not really the best forum for that discussion. I would suggest you post a topic on dreamincode.net, that's a better place for in-depth discussion of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. There is a pointer when reading files . The problem is that when using a nested loop it doesn't redirect back to the next statement in the outer loop for Python.